# extracting link from php excel reader

Tags: php, excel

I have an excel sheet with google as one of the data cells and it is a hyperlink to say http://www.google.com

Can this link be extracted using php excel reader?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: the solution is 
$data->hyperlink($row,$col,$sheet=0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To read the URL for a hyperlink in cell A1 in the current active worksheet, it's as easy as:

```
$url = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('A1')->getHyperlink()->getUrl();
```

if you're using PHPExcel

Otherwise, which PHP Excel Reader are you actually using?

Comment: As I said, which PHP Excel Reader? The one from code.google.com? the one from Sourceforge?